# App engine Java: Sum difference two arrays - How to improve performance?

Tags: java, arrays, performance, google-app-engine

I have a function in App Engine java where I compare two patterns stored in an int array.

Below is the code:

```
public static int patternMatch(int [] pattern1, int [] pattern2, int range) {

    int max = range * pattern1.length;

    int match = (pattern1.length - pattern2.length) * range;

    for(int i = 0; i < pattern2.length; i++) {
        match += Math.abs(pattern1[i] - pattern2[i]);
    }

    return (max - match) * 100 / max;
}
```

I am facing very weird problems with respect to performance of this function between the development server and deployment on app engine as listed below:

1. This function is called in a loop with the intention of finding best match(es).
2. Performance for a single iteration is critical as there are lot of iterations.
3. If I were to not have any logic in this code and directly return any integer, my overall code takes 100 ms to complete on an average.
4. The above code takes anywhere between 200 - 600 ms.
5. On the development server, if I replace "int match = (pattern1.length - pattern2.length) * range;" by "int match = Math.abs(pattern1.length - pattern2.length) * range;", somehow the performance improves bringing the time taken down to 200 - 300 ms only. No impact on deployment server.
6. If I remove "Math.abs" the performance improves bringing the average to 150 ms.
7. I tried replacing Math.abs with bit operations to derive absolute value. I see huge performance improvement on development server ~160 ms. On deployment server it makes things worse ~700 ms.

What I would like to know here is:
1. Why and how differently do Development server (Windows 7/eclipse/JDK6) and Deployment server behave in terms of performance tweaks?
2. Is there any better algorithm to the match?

Am stumped. Any help appreciated.

Comment: sounds better suited for [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Okay thanks. Will post there.

Comment: Your've tried turning the for in a tail recursion method?

Comment: Haven't tried. But won't it be slower than a for?

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question.  One problem I can think of is that there's no guarantee on the hw you run on once deployed.  On different runs, you may run on faster/slower servers.  I suspect to test it well, you'd want your various code samples to run inside the same request handler so you know they're running on the same instance.

Comment: I have had multiple runs and the average times are the same. My issue is that all my big code involving HashMap fetches with multiple loops runs much faster than this one with small calculation.

Comment: How long are your arrays for pattern1/pattern2?  The only thing that stands out is you might be able to get better CPU cache performance if you structure the two arrays as a single array of two elements corresponding to each element of pattern1/pattern2.  This might make a difference if your arrays are large.

Comment: Pattern 1 and Pattern 2 are up to 60 in size.

Comment: That's a tiny arry.  It doesn't make sense that it would take so long.  I suspect your numbers are not meaningful, for example step 5 on your list should not have much of an impact.  There might be something else in your code that's affecting the results, or maybe the way you're doing your measurement is affecting the results.

Comment: Agreed and that's what I am wondering myself. A point to note that there are around 20000 iterations to this code.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, the for loop should only run 60x.  Unless you mean this function is called 20000 times, in which case I think you can optimize that outer loop.

Comment: You are right, the outer loop runs 20000 times and has a lot of other logic. If I were to edit the above loop and not do anything within it, the execution time decreases greatly as described in the problem. So the outer code doesn't seem to be the problem.